# Trouble with making website responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm pretty new to web development and I'm having trouble making a website that I've created for my portfolio responsive. My main issue is that my website uses a sidebar navigation menu...so I'm stuck on how to incorporate that in the responsiveness. I'm thinking about using Bootstrap to make the process easier but I'm still unsure on how I could rearrange the sidebar so that it fits smaller screen sizes without making any major changes to it.

Any tips, help, suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Have you done research to see how other websites handle it?

Comment: @DJean Welcome to [so]! Unfortunately, this is not a discussion forum. We're not well equipped to answer such a broad question. I recommend you find a mentor in your area. Good luck!

Comment: Did you read the sections on making it responsive in the Bootstrap documentation?

Comment: @mcon Yes, i've done research. Maybe I'm not looking at the "right" research...thanks for your comment!

Comment: Bootstrap offers a [Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/) out of the box, which handles the responsiveness on its own (it collapses to a menu button for small devices). If the sidebar is not mandatory and the menu could stick to the top, this is a very comfortable solution. I'm not sure if it can stick to the left side though.

Comment: @jpaugh You're definitely right. My question doesn't have a specific answer. There's many ways one could fix the issue but the problem is I personally don't know how to fix it...in that case I mentor is very much needed. Thanks for your advice!!

Comment: @epascarello I've looked over it but decided to look at other resources. I'll try actually reading it this time. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I mean if you are using bootstrap, you include the JS and add the classes and it works...

Comment: @martinstoeckli I would really like for the menu to stick to the left side (only for larger devices). I don't really care if it's at the top for the smaller devices. I'll research and see if it's possible for the menu to switch positions as the screen size increases/decreases. Thanks for the tip!!

Comment: @epascarello I know. I may just be overthinking the issue. I'm going to try a menu toggle button and see if that solves my solution.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out css media queries. They allow you to change the your sidebars with the size of the browser or to disable them you browser is too small.

Comment: I will do that! Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You could use media queries or you can also use display flex for responsive behaviour: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

In css, you can use percentages when defining dimensions like so:

```
.sidebar{
width: 50%;
}
```

As long as you sidebar isn’t in any other element, it will automatically resize to 50% of the users screen. If your sidebar is contained in another element, you will have to resize the other element first.